# Alamofire 4.0 custom object & collection serializers

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I've recently migrated to Alamofire 4.0, and have had trouble implementing custom object serializers as I've been able to do in the past. My custom serializers which extended `Request` in previous versions where as such:

**ResponseObjectSerializable.swift**

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

public protocol ResponseObjectSerializable {
    init?(response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject)
}

extension Request {
    public func responseObject<T: ResponseObjectSerializable>(completionHandler: Response<T, NSError> -> Void) -> Self {
        let responseSerializer = ResponseSerializer<T, NSError> { request, response, data, error in
            guard error == nil else { return .Failure(error!) }

            let JSONResponseSerializer = Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: .AllowFragments)
            let result = JSONResponseSerializer.serializeResponse(request, response, data, error)

            switch result {
            case .Success(let value):
                if let
                    response = response,
                    responseObject = T(response: response, representation: value)
                {
                    return .Success(responseObject)
                } else {
                    let failureReason = "JSON could not be serialized into response object: \(value)"
                    let error = Error.errorWithCode(.JSONSerializationFailed, failureReason: failureReason)
                    return .Failure(error)
                }
            case .Failure(let error):
                return .Failure(error)
            }
        }

        return response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

**ResponseCollectionSerializable.swift**

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

public protocol ResponseCollectionSerializable {
    static func collection(response response: NSHTTPURLResponse, representation: AnyObject) -> [Self]
}

extension Alamofire.Request {
    public func responseCollection<T: ResponseCollectionSerializable>(completionHandler: Response<[T], NSError> -> Void) -> Self {
        let responseSerializer = ResponseSerializer<[T], NSError> { request, response, data, error in
            guard error == nil else { return .Failure(error!) }

            let JSONSerializer = Request.JSONResponseSerializer(options: .AllowFragments)
            let result = JSONSerializer.serializeResponse(request, response, data, error)

            switch result {
            case .Success(let value):
                if let response = response {
                    return .Success(T.collection(response: response, representation: value))
                } else {
                    let failureReason = "Response collection could not be serialized due to nil response"
                    let error = Error.errorWithCode(.JSONSerializationFailed, failureReason: failureReason)
                    return .Failure(error)
                }
            case .Failure(let error):
                return .Failure(error)
            }
        }

        return response(responseSerializer: responseSerializer, completionHandler: completionHandler)
    }
}
```

How should/what are the new equivalents to this in the Alamofire 4.0 version? Or should this be approached in a completely different manner.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Any luck?